# Is there a way to modify Frontier_exploration such that it can work autonomously?

Tags: ros, frontier-exploration, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi.

I am trying to implement a robot that will map and navigate an environment on its own. I have searched a lot about existing ros packages and I THINK FRONTIER_EXPLORATION would do this for me. However, frontier_exploration requires manual instructions in terms of making the polygon etc. so i was wondering is there a way i can run frontier exploration and the robot just maps and navigate the environment on its own?

Or is there any other package that does this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/286547/is-there-a-way-to-modify-frontier_exploration-such-that-it-can-work-autonomously?/) by [hasnain](https://answers.ros.org/users/33864/hasnain/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2018-03-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you ask frontier_exploration to explore an empty polygon, it will explore indefinitely. Either that, you can write your own high-level controller to generate polygons and areas to explore.

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2018-04-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [taka1995](https://answers.ros.org/users/45327/taka1995/) on 2019-09-24**:
hi，how can I save the map automatically?I don't know what topic to subscribe to for the map to complete the discovery.